# DateTime variable goes out of scope

Tags: c#, code-behind

I've got this block of code in a code-behind:

```
while (DT1.Read())
{
  //Read the record into an "array", so you can find the SProc and View names
  int MyRptID = Convert.ToInt32(DT1[0]);
  string MyRptName = DT1[1].ToString();
  string MyRptSproc = DT1[2].ToString();
  string MySQLView = DT1[3].ToString();

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.txtStartDate.Text))
  {
     DateTime MyStDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtStartDate.Text);
  }

  if (MyStDate != null)
  {
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStartDate.Text;
  }
```

MyStDate is underlined in red, and when I hover over it I get a popup that says, "The name 'MyStDate' does not exist in the current context."  Can anyone tell me why this is?  Does it have to do with the fact that it's outside the bracket?  If so, how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `MyStDate` is the if condition. A variable is not visible outside its scope so you need to declare `MyStDate` outside of the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `MyStDate` before the if statement.  That is why it is going out of scope.

```
while (DT1.Read())
{
    //Read the record into an "array", so you can find the SProc and View names
    int MyRptID = Convert.ToInt32(DT1[0]);
    string MyRptName = DT1[1].ToString();
    string MyRptSproc = DT1[2].ToString();
    string MySQLView = DT1[3].ToString();
    DateTime MyStDate;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.txtStartDate.Text))
    {
        MyStDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtStartDate.Text);
    }

    if (MyStDate != null)
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStartDate.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `DateTime MyStDate` inside the `if` block, so it's not accessible in the next `if` block (it's out of scope).

You'll want to define the variable *outside* the first `if` block, so it's accessible later in the method.

```
DateTime myStDate;

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.txtStartDate.Text))
    myStDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtStartDate.Text);

if (myStDate != null)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = myStDate;
```

Actually, it looks like you have a few issues with your code.

Try this instead of what you've currently got:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtStartDate.Text))
{
    DateTime myStDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse("txtStartDate.Text", out myStDate))
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = myStDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DO this instead:

```
DateTime MyStDate;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.txtStartDate.Text))
{
     MyStDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtStartDate.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the instance of `MyStDate` outside the if statement. MyStDate is not visible to anything outside the scope it's declared.

```
DateTime MyStDate = null;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.txtStartDate.Text))
    MyStDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtStartDate.Text);

if(MyStDate != null)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = MyStDate;
```